# JavaFX: Error on using an Array of VBox in Netbeans

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to make several VBoxes by making an Array and then setting their properties by using a for loop like this:

```
VBox boxes[] = new VBox[5];

    for(VBox box : boxes) {
        box.setMaxSize(150, 150);
        box.setMinSize(150, 150);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        box.setStyle("-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-bordor-color: black; -fx-bordor-width: 1px;");
    }
```

The code builds just fine, but everytime I run run it I get the following error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafxhelloworld.JavaFXHelloWorld.start(JavaFXHelloWorld.java:36)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application javafxhelloworld.JavaFXHelloWorld
```

I've tried to it with a normal for loop, and it still gives me the same errors. I'm using Netbeans for this. My question is, what's going on? How do I fix it? I'm new to JavaFX so excuse me if I'm doing something glaringly wrong.

Comment: Why not use an `ArrayList` or `List`? Also, you allocate space for 5 `VBox`, but you don't have anything in the actual array.

Comment: A array created using `new VBox[5]` is initialized with `null` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Here is a very simple explain:***

If you create your `Array` with the code:

`VBox boxes[] = new VBox[5];`



You create a kind of a box with **5 drawers** (in my case 8 because I have no other picture)...

So your `Array` looks like this:

[image]

Every drawer contains null, because the `VBox boxes[] = new VBox[5];` line creates only a empty box with "null-Arrow"s. **This is why your `for` throws a `NullPointerExeption`**

***So what must I do??***
You have to initialize these boxes...

Sample:

```
boxes[0] = new VBox();
```

But why `[0]`? Because a `Array` starts counting by id = 0

After this your box looks like this:

[image]

**---- Wrap Up ----**

1. Create a Empty box: `VBox boxes[] = new VBox[5];`
2. Init these drawers: `boxes[0] = new VBox();`, `boxes[1] = new VBox();`, ...
3. Your `for` is working now...

P.S. your can init the box also in this way:

```
VBox boxes[] = {new VBox(), new VBox(), new VBox(), ...};
```

This saves you these rows:

```
boxes[0] = new VBox();
```

**The best Way is (because it is dynamical):**

```
for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxed[i] = new VBox();
}
```

Or

```
Stream.generate(VBox::new).limit(5).toArray(VBox[]::new);
```

(Thanks to fabian)

Comment: Probably the creation of the `VBox`es should be done from a loop (or using a stream). This way it's simpler to modify the array size and it keeps the code DRY. `for (int i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) { boxed[i] = new VBox();} ` or `Stream.generate(VBox::new).limit(5).toArray(VBox[]::new);`